# Spring-Security @EnableOAuth2Sso Filter for particular domains

Tags: java, oauth, spring-boot, single-sign-on, openid

I am trying to use Spring Security OAuth with Google OpenID and it works great, but I would like to restrict it to a single domain. I think it's called hosted domain in Google, but I can't seem to make it work in the Spring config.

I have **hd=domain.com** but that doesn't stop the login attempt.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, should I do a custom filter etc#

Thanks